# Create friendly url in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, string, seo, friendly-url

Hi i'm using Laravel 5 and i have an array with 5 element

> array(5) { [0]=> string(25) "Ruby on rails" [1]=> string(14)
>   "Web Develop" [2]=> string(12) "Asp.net" [3]=> string(3) "Php" [4]=>
>   string(4) "Java" }

And i use this function to create friendly url

```
foreach ($tag as $value)
{
  $href = str_slug($value, "-");
}
```

And i get this

> string(18) "Ruby-on-rails" string(10) "Web-Develop" string(9)
>   "asp-net" string(3) "php" string(4) "java"

So how i can foreach those string i get and pass into view to make friendly url.Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it the right way, you are trying to merge all your tags together to one URL. The problem is, that you create a slug for each single tag and not for all tags.

The output you gave us seems to be an array, so you could use the php function `implode` to stick them all together. For example:

`$slug = implode('-', $yourArrayWithSingleSlugs )`

This would put a `-` between each single slug in your array and combine them to a string.

Comment: Still not working.I mean i have 5 tag Ruby on rails .... when i click to one tag like  Ruby on rails  i will have exact same url name like  Ruby-on-rails

Comment: Usually this should work. I would recommend you to show us more of your surrounding code ...

Comment: I only have this to get the string
$tag_content = TagContent::where('job_id', '=', $data['job']->id)->first();
$data['tag'] = explode(',', $tag_content->tag_content);

Comment: and you are trying to get an url like "ruby-on-rails-web-develop-asp-net-php-java" ? or am i misunderstanding you?